# Making an image go full screen like in photos app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview

how can you make a UIImage go full screen, but not the actual frame of the image, but like the photos in the iOS photos app, where you tap a photo and it goes to a special full screen mode, where you can zoom in etc.
many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a `UIImageView` as subview to a `UIScrollView` with it's frame equal to the size of the screen.

Set your `UIScrollViewDelegate` and implement the delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.yourImageView;
}
```

Attach  two tap gesture recognizers to the imageView:

- Single tap recognizer -> for zooming back to normal frame
- Double tap recognizer -> for zooming in rapidly to specific spot

Implement your tapGestureRecognizer selectors and direct the zoom logic using:

```
CGPoint location = [tapRecognizer locationInView:self.yourImageView]; // Location of tap
```

and

```
[self.scrollView zoomToRect:whateverRect animated:YES]; //Zooming in/out to locations
[self.scrollView setZoomScale:whateverScale animated:YES];
```